# Detailtext is not showing in case?

Tags: objective-c

I have a case but the detailtext is not showing? Does anyone know what te problem is?

i used: `UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIViewController *controller;        
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch(indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
        {
            NSLog(@"Case 0");
            controller = [[wed1 alloc] init]; //WithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Wedstrijden!";
        }
            break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   case 0:
    {
        NSLog(@"Case 0");

        controller = [[wed1 alloc] init]; //WithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

//created a controller

```
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

//at his point, you are showing next ViewController's view

```
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Wedstrijden!";
```

//here you are changing the text of the text for current tableView's cell (which is actually going to be off the screen as new controller's view will be shown after previous statement execution)

```
    }
```

with the piece of code you shared - I don't find anything wrong here, the detail text should not be visible as this view will be gone.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand why you'd want to set the detail text on a cell after pushing a new view controller. As samfisher said, when the user presses the first cell, in case 0, the new view controller will be alloc'd, init'd and then pushed, and after that you set the detail text to "Wedstrijden".

I'm assuming you're probably just confused between which property to use. My question to you is: when and where do you want this text to appear?

Answer (score 0):

If the cell was created with the style `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`, the detail text label isn't displayed. In `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` implementation, you may create the cell with style `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle` or `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `UIListContentConfiguration` instead, or subtitle won't show.

```
#import <UIKit/UIListContentConfiguration.h>
```

And in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"AddressCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(cell==nil){
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"AddressCell"];
    }
    NSRange range = [self.dataArray[indexPath.row] rangeOfString:@","];
    NSString *street;
    NSString *restAddress;
    if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
        street = [self.dataArray[indexPath.row] substringToIndex:range.location];
        restAddress= [self.dataArray[indexPath.row] substringFromIndex:range.location + 1];
    }    
    UIListContentConfiguration *configuration = cell.defaultContentConfiguration;
    configuration.text=street;
    configuration.image=kImage(@"Location");
    configuration.secondaryText=restAddress;
    cell.contentConfiguration = configuration;
    return cell;
}
```

Will look like this:
[image]